# Eyes won't follow mesh for animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to experiment with an animation. When I move some controllers, the eyes start to stretch after a certain offset.
Here is the blend file[image]

I used automatic weighting, the metarig and the generated controllers. Some of the controllers don't work as planned, but I can managed to make some poses. I also deleted the WTGS rigs.

EDIT: the eyes are not eyeballs, they are a separate mesh, along with the hair, which is consisted of bezier curves.

https://gofile.io/?c=m5eyWj

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but I just deleted all the vertex groups for the eye mesh except **DEF-spine.006** and **assign** 1.000 weight to all verts of the eyes mesh then moved the **armature modifier above** the data transfer modifier, and they move with the head bone (DEF-spine.006 is the head deform bone, I think).  GL OP

Comment: I'll try this, thanks! Also, how come some controllers don't work properly? The skinning, although automatic, is done accurately. There are so many details when it comes to animation.

Comment: the few I checked seem to work; if you mean some of the legs and arms aren't moving, then you need to set the IK/FK switch to the correct setting; if you don't know the difference between IK and FK, I suggest watching a few tutorials, it's really amazing how complex it all is.  GL